# System.IndexOutOfRangeException : clientside js to serverside c#

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays

I'm trying to send some output from a client side `Javascript` code to a server side `C#` code.

But my current problem is, when i try to pass multiple parameters back to the server, then i receive the error:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: The index was outside the array
>   range.

What could cause this problem?
**Javascript** part where I send the variables back to the server:

```
var tempStorage = {
    0: atmlist[index][i][0],
    1: betrag
};

API.triggerServerEvent(responseName, tempStorage);
```

The complete **Javascript** function:

```
atmSubMenus[index].OnItemSelect.connect(function (sender, item, i)
{
    if (atmlist[index][i][0] === 0)
    {
        API.triggerServerEvent(responseName, atmlist[index][i][0]);
        atmSubMenus[index].Visible = false;
        API.showCursor(false);
    }
    else if (atmlist[index][i][0] === 1)
    {
        var betrag = API.getUserInput("", 10);

        var tempStorage = {
            0: atmlist[index][i][0],
            1: betrag
        };

        API.triggerServerEvent(responseName, tempStorage);
        atmSubMenus[index].Visible = false;
        API.showCursor(false);
    }
    else if (atmlist[index][i][0] === 2)
    {

    }
    else if (atmlist[index][i][0] === 3) {

    }
});
```

And here's the **C#** part, which causes the error:

```
int betrag = (int)args[1];
sender.sendChatMessage("~y~[BANK]:~w~ Betrag: " + betrag);
```

And the complete function:

```
public void onClientEventTrigger(Client sender, string name, object[] args)
{
    if (name == "ATM_SELECTED")
    {
        int function = (int)args[0];

        if (function == 0)
        {
            int money = database.playerDatabase.getBankAmount(sender);

            if (money == 0)
            {
                sender.sendChatMessage("~y~[BANK]:~w~ Du hast kein Bank guthaben.");
            }
            else
            {
                sender.sendChatMessage("~y~[BANK]:~w~ Dein Bankguthaben beträgt: $" + money);
            }
        }
        else if (function == 1)
        {
            int betrag = (int)args[1];
            sender.sendChatMessage("~y~[BANK]:~w~ Betrag: " + betrag);
        }
        else if (function == 2)
        {
            sender.sendChatMessage("~y~[BANK]:~w~ Event 3 wurde getriggert");
        }
        else if (function == 3)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: "What could cause this problem?" - An index being out of range. Your next step should be to find out exactly where this is happening, what the index was, and what the array size was. We can't help you with any of those.

Comment: The binder can't figure out what you want to do with tempStorage.  Instead of sending an object, try sending an array: `tempStorage = [tmlist[index][i][0], betrag ];`  Your problem isn't about the index out of range, it's figuring out how to get MVC to convert the post values into your parameters correctly.